# How to run a fabric script over a SOCKS proxy?

Tags: python, proxy, fabric, socks

I have a SOCKS proxy setup to a gateway server which is created by setting up a host definition in my `ssh_config` to use `DynamicForward localhost:9876`. To connect with SSH to the remote server I've setup another host definition to use `ProxyCommand /usr/bin/nc -x localhost:9876 %h %p` which is all working fine.

However my fabric script needs to connect to that remote server. How can I tell it to use the SOCKS proxy when it connects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tunnelling is now (March 2013) supported by Fabric natively: see the [discussion](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/38) leading to the changes in code and the [commit message](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/commit/5e9cd464916bce0b81c60f6d442821af929486da) with a bit of rationale.

Answer (score 2):

Fabric's [SSH layer](https://bugs.launchpad.net/paramiko/+bug/483697) does not support gateways or proxies at the moment but they "may end up patching/[forking](http://code.fabfile.org/issues/show/275) it sometime to add that functionality." (from [here](http://code.fabfile.org/issues/show/344)).

There's also an outstanding issue on Fabric to [implement tunneling](http://code.fabfile.org/issues/show/38).

[This blog post](http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2009/sep/22/easy-fabric-deployment-part-1-gitmercurial-and-ssh/) suggests overriding the run function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tsocks and the OpenSSH client's built-in support for creating SOCKS tunnels. It requires a bit of configuration but it works fine. Below is how I got started on Ubuntu 10.04.

```bash
# Install the tsocks library and shell script.
sudo apt-get install tsocks

# Configure the range of IP addresses you need access to.
sudo nano /etc/tsocks.conf

# Use the OpenSSH client to create a socks proxy (stepping
# stones are hosts used to gain access to private subnets).
ssh -D 1080 stepping.stone

# Now connect to any given address in your configured range.
# tsocks will intercept the connection and route it using
# the SOCKS proxy we created with the previous command.
tsocks ssh 1.2.3.4
```

The fact that Fabric doesn't work without a VPN connection was a deal breaker for me, so this is a great solution; all it requires is SSH access to one host.

Answer (score 0):

on `Fabric (1.12.0)`([doc](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/env.html#use-ssh-config)):

```
 env.use_ssh_config = True
```